# half circle Toolbar Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

can someone tell me how to create a custom toolbar like this [image: toolbar] .

how to add that custom toolbar?

this is my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/praktik"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<include layout="@layout/content_main_games"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make a 9 patch drawable... You're not going to get that toolbar purely in xml

Comment: and then what should i do? @cricket_007

Comment: It's easy if you use photo shop it's a rectangular png with transparent pixels under the curve.

Answer (score 0):

Use this design to set background.

```
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#00B0EA" />

    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="400dp"
    android:left="-100dp"
    android:right="-100dp"
    android:top="-200dp">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:endColor="#65FFFFFF"
            android:startColor="#65FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="402dp"
    android:left="-100dp"

    android:right="-100dp"
    android:top="-280dp">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: I don't know what is happening. I have added layer list before item tag but its is not showing in this code snippet. I am trying to figure out this but for now to resolve this error wrap all item in **layer list** tag of xml..